# Cech homology (!) of the Warsaw Circle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homology

Can anyone can give me a reference to the fact that first Cech homology (not cohomology!) group of the Warsaw Circle is $\mathbb{R}$? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: http://www2.math.su.se/reports/2008/4/2008-4.pdf --- remark 2.7